# Disable member from apache load balancer

Tags: apache

I am using apache load balancer Registered two member. I can see the load balancer manager members.
When I trying to disable a member from CURL, I am unable to disable but when I am trying to disable from GUI I am able to.

Below is my curl command:

```
curl -s -XPOST "http://${server}:${port}/${manager}?" -d b="${balancer}" -d w="${worker}" -d nonce="${nonce}" -d status_D=1 -d lf=1 -d status_I=0 -d status_H=0 -d ls=0 -d wr= -d rr=
curl -s -XPOST "http://${server}:${port}/${manager}?" -d b="${balancer}" -d w="${worker}" -d nonce="${nonce}" -d dw=Disable
```

Below is my load balancer configuration

```
ProxyRequests off
<Proxy balancer://apachelb22>
        BalancerMember http://103.26.112.105:8081
        BalancerMember http://152.87.14.10:8082
        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

<Location /balancer-manager>
        SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://apachelb22/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://apachelb22/
```

When I tried to disable using curl command I am getting below error

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/balancer-manager
```

My apache version is Apache/2.2.34

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Regards
Satyanvesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below curl command and with that I am able to disable the worker

```
curl -s -o /dev/null "${target}?b=${balancer}&w=${worker}&nonce=${nonce}&status_D=1&lf=1&ls=0&wr=&rr="
```